# Permission for "Send an activation email now?" Option

Tags: users, admin, permissions

So it looks like site admins have the ability to choose whether or not to send a new user an Activation Email through the "Send an activation email now?" checkbox option on the Register a new user page on the Craft back-end.

I want to give this permission to a set of "Managers" user/permission group, but I cannot find the option that allows this permission to be usable.

The "Manager" user group currently has all "User" permissions checked.  Is the only way to fix this to make them an admin?

Was hoping to be a bit more granular. Any insights would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This feature was added in Craft 3.3.5, see the [changelog](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG-v3.md#changed-2).

If you update to this version, your users should be able to control whether the activation email is sent.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out soon. Been holding off on an update for a while as I'm worried about some compatibility issues. Keep you posted.